# What is purpose of permission ACCESS_MTK_MMHW

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest, android-permissions

i just went through an existing code of an app.there is one permission in manifest file: `android.permission.ACCESS_MTK_MMHW` .I searched on google but i didn't get satisfactory answers.can some one please tell what is the purpose of this permission.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way to discover what a permission grants access to. Try to install this application in your cellphone. When a popup appears describing the permissions this app needs, pay attention to every one of them.

In this case, based on what i've searched, `MTK` refers to `MediaTek`, which is a manufacturer of eletronic chips. Unfortunately there is little to none information on the internet about this `MMHW`, but it must be a hardware provided by this company and this app needs permission to use it (lucky guess?).

Answer (score 0):

The MMHW access used for fm radio. It is used to access fm radio chip.